# Testing Symfony DELETE routes

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm setting up phpunit for testing, and started with the Controller routes.  When I test the 'GET' methods, they work fine.  However, the 'DELETE' methods throw an MethodNotAllowedHttpException.  NOTE: I'm not testing adding/removing database entities yet, just validating routes.

```
* @Route("/deviceprofile/{deviceprofile_id}/delete",
*     name="deviceprofile_delete",
*     methods={"DELETE"})
```

The test class:

```
class DeviceProfileControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testRouteDelete()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->followRedirects(true);
        $client->request('DELETE', '/deviceprofile/1/delete');
        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }
}
```

The phpunit error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: No route found for "GET /1/delete": Method Not Allowed (Allow: DELETE)
```

Based on the error, it appears that my **$client->request** is only doing 'GETs' regardless of the method listed.

So, what function should I be calling to test a 'DELETE' method?

**EDIT:** here is the **bin/console debug:router** listing:

```
deviceprofile_delete    DELETE    ANY    ANY 
   /deviceprofile/{deviceprofile_id}/delete
```

**UPDATE:** it also appears that 'POST' method only routes also fail.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between testing DELETE or any other method. Try using `php bin/console debug:router` to debug routes.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  Edited the question

Comment: The issue isn't the route itself, the route works great.   The problem is that when calling the WebTestCase::createClient()->request, it doesn't appear to like 'DELETE' as a method.  As the phpunit error suggests, it's still trying to do a 'GET' for that route, not a 'DELETE'

Comment: Maybe it's a cache issue? Try clearing cache for with `--env=test`

Comment: Cleared the cache, phpunit still spits out:  No route found for "GET /deviceprofile/1/delete": Method Not Allowed (Allow: DELETE)

The request SHOULD be:  "DELETE /deviceprofile/1/delete"

Comment: do you have - by any chance - an old test somewhere, where you access the same uri/route but with GET? because the two http clients used most frequently in tests will happily accept `DELETE` and pass it on.

Comment: No, I just started working on my tests for the app a few days ago, and this is why I'm surprised by the error message.  I'm assuming I did something incorrect, like using the incorrect test function to try and test the DELETE method of my route.  I'm only guessing that the request would be DELETE <route>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the `$client->followRedirects(true);`, phpunit fails assertions of 301 redirects.

And with those problems now visible, and it showed that I was not properly authenticating.

Ended up finding this document that helped:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing/http_authentication.html